# error visual studio code app.js

Tags: vscode

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Inicio from './Components/Inicio';
import Users  from './Components/Users';
import Comentarios from './Components/Comentarios';
import Albunes from './Components/Albunes';
```

entonces

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container mt-5">
        <div className="btn-group">
          <Link to="/" className="btn btn-dark">
             Inicio
          </Link>
          <Link to="/Usuarios" className="btn btn-dark">
             Usuarios
          </Link>
          <Link to="/Comentarios" className="btn btn-dark">
             Comentarios
          </Link>
          <Link to="/Albunes" className="btn btn-dark">
             Albunes
          </Link>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact><Inicio/></Route>
          <Route path="/Usuarios"><Users/></Route>
          <Route path="/Comentarios"><Comentarios/></Route>
          `introducir el código aquí`<Route path="/Albunes"><Albunes/></Route>       
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```